# How do you Change Array Index Keys to MySQL values

Tags: php, mysql

I need help working with arrays. I have an array of data from a MySQL query. After printing it in a for loop, I get the following array_flip:

```
    Array ( 

   [Duru 60] => 0 
   [Maxwell 50] => 1 
   [Fashanu 70] => 2 
   [Nwankwo 80] => 3 
   [Obi 0] => 4 

   )
```

The array value is a combination of 2 fields name and total score. What I want to achieve is an array like so:

```
   Array (

   [Duru 60] => 60 
   [Maxwell 50] => 50 
   [Fashanu 70] => 70 
   [Nwankwo 80] => 80 
   [Obi 0] => 0 

   )
```

What I want to achieve is to change the default array numeric keys (0,1,2,3,4) to total score obtained from the query.

Here is the code that gave the first array block:

**PHP code begins**

```
    $dataA = array();

    foreach($data as $key => $val){

$dataC = $val['lastname']." ".$val['total'];
array_push($dataA,($dataC));

     }
     $dataD = (array_flip($dataA));

     print_r($dataD);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dataA = array();
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    $dataK = $val['lastname']." ".$val['total'];
    $dataV = $val['total'];
    $dataA[$dataK] = $dataV;
}
print_r($dataA);
```

Comment: this is wot i neec. U guys are the best. Will surely be back for more

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $dataA = array();

    foreach($data as $key => $val){

           $dataC = $val['lastname']." ".$val['total'];

           $dataA[$dataC] = $val['total'];

     }

     print_r($dataA);
```

Comment: Array ( [60] => Duru 60 [Duru 60] => 0 [50] => Maxwell 50 [Maxwell 50] => 1 [70] => Fashanu 70 [Fashanu 70] => 2 [80] => Nwankwo 80 [Nwankwo 80] => 3 [0] => Obi 0 [Obi 0] => 4 )

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do:

```
$newData = array();
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
  $newData[$val['lastname'] . ' ' . $val['total']] = $val['total'];
}
print_r($newData);
```